# Downloaded file with Excel VBA is corrupted

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ado

My Excel VBA macro sends a POST multipart/form-data request to an API and receives a application/pdf file as a response.

This is the relevant part:

```
Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
xhr.Open "POST", Uri, False
xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & strBoundary
xhr.setRequestHeader "X-Api-Key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
xhr.send (strBody)
If xhr.Status Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write xhr.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile outputFileName, 2
    oStream.Close
End If
Set xhr = Nothing
```

The downloaded PDF document is unreadable by any PDF reader. I checked its contents and it is *almost* the same as the downloaded document from other clients (eg Postman, cURL), *which are valid PDF documents (ie can be open in PDF readers) [Edited]*.

For example, when opening the PDF documents in VS Code:

The VBA macro downloaded file:

[image]

Compare it to the PDF downloaded with Postman (Check the last line in the picture):

[image]

If it was a text file, it would seem as an encoding problem, but as I am using the ADODB.Stream with `Type = 1` that should handle binary files well.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think it has to do with the [POST implementation](https://www.guru99.com/difference-get-post-http.html) _It is not possible to save data as the data sent by the POST method is not visible in the URL_. Perhaps you may try with selenium to do so?

Comment: @Sgdva I am asking to save the response of a POST request, not the request itself.

Comment: What's the API? Does it have documentation? Which file are you trying to download? What do you want us to see from the last line? Have you managed a successful download with a different method?

Comment: @QHarr please read the question

Comment: I have re-read it. No API documentation links, no API endpoint given, you imply end lines are different but don't say much beyond that (how are they different?) The words successful/worked etc do not appear any where. `its contents and it is almost the same as the downloaded document from other clients (eg Postman, cURL).` - might imply not corrupted with latter methods (as with title and last sentence) but no where does it state they do work. I asked because the answer to all of my questions are not clear to me. Perhaps they are clear to others who can help you.

Comment: If it works with cURL then try adding `xhr.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "curl/7.55.1"`

Comment: @QHarr thanks for your answer. The file downloaded with Postman and cURL is OK ie can be open in PDF readers. I edited the question to make it explicit. I intentionally left out the API documentation, endpoint, and the creation of the multipart/form-data strBody as they work fine, and the API requires credentials I am not able to share here. I guess the request works well (as the request is processed by the API) but there is something in the responseBody being converted to a stream and then to a file that garbles the "binarey" parts of the PDF.